# ¿Cómo hago para que me pida repetir la contraseña o el usuario si está mal?

Tags: java

Tengo un problema con java NetBeans. Necesito que el programa no me cierre y me repita si la contraseña o el usuario si es que esta mal, la idea es usarlo en un menú para que pregunte el usuario y contraseña y si está mal que lo repita hasta que lo digite correctamente.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class log {

   
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String U = "admin";
        String P = "1234";
                
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Bienvenido al Sistema \n" 
                + "Primero debemos verificar sus datos.");
                
        String user = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese el Usuario: ");
        String pass = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese la contraseña: ");
        
        while(true){
            
            if(U.equals(user)){
            if(P.equals(pass)){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Bienvenido ");
                break;
                
            }else{
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, 
                        "Contraseña Incorrecta", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                
                
            }
        }else{
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    "El usuario es invalido!", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            
            
        
        }
        
            
        }
        
        
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes añadir una variable booleana `encontrado` que haga que el bucle se repita hasta que sea verdadera. Además, se deben pedir los datos al usuario dentro del bucle.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class log {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String U = "admin";
        String P = "1234";
        boolean encontrado = false; // Variable para seguir ejecutando el bucle hasta que el usuario introduzca los datos correctos

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Bienvenido al Sistema \n"
                + "Primero debemos verificar sus datos.");

        // Inicializar variables, pero solicitar la entrada del usuario en el bucle.
        String user = "";
        String pass = "";

        while(!encontrado){ // Ejecutar el bucle hasta que el usuario introduzca los datos correctos
            // Pedir aquí los datos al usuario para solicitar de nuevo si falla.
            user = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese el Usuario: ");
            pass = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese la contraseña: ");

            if(U.equals(user)){
                if(P.equals(pass)){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Bienvenido ");
                    encontrado = true; // Se abandona el bucle

                }else{
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                            "Contraseña Incorrecta", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                }
            }else{
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                        "El usuario es invalido!", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
        }
    }
}
```